# Code-generated radiobuttons check selection

Tags: android, radio-button

I have some code that generates in the activity some radiobuttons:

```
public void drawRAnswers(int pst){
    int drawables = qmclist.get(pst).getAnswers().size();
    RadioGroup l1 = new RadioGroup(this);
    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i=0;i<drawables;i++){
        RadioButton rd = new RadioButton(this);
        rd.setId(i);
        rd.setText(current.getAnswers().get(i).getAns());
        l1.addView(rd);
    }
    parentLinearLayout.addView(l1, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
}
```

What I want to do is be able to verify which ones (radiobuttons) are checked when I click a button:

```
public void onAddAnswer(View v){
    position++;
    delete();
    drawRAnswers(position);
}
```

For now, what this button does is only load the next set of radiobuttons in the view and delete the current ones, but I don't check which ones are selected. Do you know how I could do this in this `onAddAnswer` method? I would like to put the text of each selected radiobutton in a list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out myself. Here is what I have done:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioGroup currentGroup;
    ...
    public void onAddAnswer(View v){

    if (currentGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Veuillez sélectionner au moins une réponse",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        int selectedId = currentGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton selectedRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedRadio.getText().toString()+" is selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        position++;
        delete();
        updateData(position);
    }
}
    ...
    public void drawRAnswers(int pst){
    int drawables = qmclist.get(pst).getAnswers().size();
    RadioGroup l1 = new RadioGroup(this);
    currentGroup = l1;
    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i=0;i<drawables;i++){
        RadioButton rd = new RadioButton(this);
        rd.setId(i);
        rd.setText(current.getAnswers().get(i).getAns());
        l1.addView(rd);
    }
    parentLinearLayout.addView(l1, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
}
}
```

So basically what I am doing is have a RadioGroup for every time I draw radiobuttons, match it with the currentGroup and check if I have (or not) any radiobuttons selected. If yes, then I find out which one.